# cant get basic kogrid to display (with jsfiddle)

Tags: knockout.js, kogrid

I'm trying my first kogrid I'm trying to use it to display a simple data grid. The code runs, but doenst show anything.
jsfiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/z5Pdy/6/

HTML IS

```
    <div style="height: 300px; width:600px;"
    data-bind="koGrid: { data: brokerCommissions.list,
                           isMultiSelect: false,
                           selectedItem: selectedBroker,
                           columnDefs: [
{ field: 'broker', displayName: 'First Name' }
]}"></div>
```

javascript is

```
    function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.brokerCommissions = ko.observableArray([
        {
        "broker": "y",
        "c": 0},
    {
        "broker": "x",
        "c": 0}
    ]);
    self.selectedBroker = ko.observable();
}

function initializeKO() {
    VM = new AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(VM);
}
initializeKO();
```

can anyone tell me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're not including the koGrid JS file correctly (if you check out your browser's dev tools you'll see a 404 being returned when the script is requested).

Your other problem is that you're using `brokerCommissions.list`, which does not exist. Try just `brokerCommissions` instead:

```
<div style="height: 300px; width:600px;"
    data-bind="koGrid: { data: brokerCommissions,
                           isMultiSelect: false,
                           selectedItem: selectedBroker,
                           columnDefs: [
{ field: 'broker', displayName: 'First Name' }
]}"></div>​
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z5Pdy/8/

Comment: isMultiSelect should be multiSelect when using version 2.1.1